# Problems packaging and deploying an ADF application in an external WLS

Tags: java, deployment, package, weblogic, oracle-adf

I'm using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0, which has an embedded 10.3.5 WebLogic Server.

When I test my application by right-click on my page and Run... in embedded WLS, everything works perfectly. It works with any page and any flow.

Now, I have to deploy the same application in an external 10.3.6 WLS.

First, I have package the application in an EAR using JDeveloper Wizard. I have done right-click in application --> Deploy --> MyApplication... --> Select Deploy to EAR.

Then, when .ear file is built, I run startWebLogic (I have previously created a domain with ADF Runtime options) and deploy the .ear as an application.

I have lots of warnings, but final message is deployment is ok.

So, my surprise is I get a NullPointerException in the first page I test, in the first access to an ADF Iterator/View  in the Java class:

```
DCIteratorBinding iter = ADFUtils.findIterator("BusinessDataView1Iterator");  
ViewObject vo = iter.getViewObject(); -- iter is null
```

This had worked lot of times in embedded 10.3.5 WLS.

10.3.6 WLS console output is this:

```
19-feb-2014 15:04:26 oracle.adfinternal.controller.metadata.MetadataServiceImpl$Bootstrap logActivityWarnings  
WARNING: ADFc: /WEB-INF/adfc-config-reportes.xml:  
...  
...  
...  
...  
ADVERTENCIA: ADFc: /WEB-INF/adfc-config.xml:  
19-feb-2014 15:04:26 oracle.adfinternal.controller.metadata.MetadataServiceImpl$Bootstrap logBeanWarnings  
ADVERTENCIA: ADFc: Se ha detectado una definicion de bean gestionado duplicada para 'backing_views_administracion_inicio'.  
...  
...  
...  
...  
19-feb-2014 15:04:30 oracle.adfinternal.controller.util.WebAppConfigFactory createConfig  
INFO: ADFc: Se estß utilizando la vista '<null-value>' como la pßgina inicial de la aplicaci¾n.  
19-feb-2014 15:04:32 oracle.adf.share.jndi.ReferenceStoreHelper getReferencesMapEx  
ADVERTENCIA: Incomplete connection reference object for connection:MY_DB_JDBC  
19-feb-2014 15:04:47 oracle.adfinternal.controller.application.AdfcExceptionHandler handleException  
GRAVE: ADFc: al manejar una excepci¾n, el manejador de excepciones de la aplicaci¾n ha devuelto una nueva excepci¾n.  
java.lang.NullPointerException  
        at com.mypackage.Gestion.<init>(Gestion.java:37)
```

Between dots sections, there are some similar warnings.

I have checked .ear file (contains a .war), decompressing it (the .war too) in a different folder and searching for duplications by text in any file, and adfc-config.xml exists only once in the `.ear`.

How can I solve this? Have anyone had any similar problems when deploying in an external WLS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally solved my issue.

The steps are:

- Configure WL 10.3.6 as an embedded WLS in JDeveloper.
- Configure Diagnostics in WLS: http://jdeveloperfaq.blogspot.com.es/2009/12/faq-7-how-to-configure-adf-diagnostics.html
- Run application in WLS 10.3.6. Now, there are lot of logs and I see the problem in DataBindings file. AppModule connection name and DataBinding reference to that AppModule were mismatching. Fix it: http://www.emmersonmiranda.net/2011/07/jbo-33005-configuration-appmodulelocal.html
- Then, a classic JNDI fail. It's very important to name JDBC DataSource with some conventions with Connection name. See this: http://mrk-group.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/unable-to-lookup-data-source-at-context.html

Finally it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. upgrade the jdeveloper to ADF version deployed on weblogic 10.3.6.
2. clear all your projects in jdeveloper
3. deploy the application with ear profile.

--
Peddi

Comment: thank you for your idea. JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0 has embedded WLS 10.3.5, but it's compatible with 10.3.6
I can't find any JDeveloper with embedded 10.3.6